# Как осуществить проектирование архитектуры информационной системы с использованием базы данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Здравствуйте,уважаемые программисты.
Целью моей дипломной работы является разработка информационной системы. Языком программирования выбран C#. Программа должна удаленно через Web-интерфейс подключаться к БД, находящихся на сервере учебного заведения. Платформой была выбрана технология [ADO.NET](http://ADO.NET). Возможности программы- авторизация пользователей, просмотр и скачивание документов.
Подскажите, направьте, с чего начать? Информация есть, но ввиду отсутствия опыта не знаю, как начать работу и вообще, в каком порядке выполнять.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @Tyler, начинайте как все - предметная область -> аналоги -> планирование -> проектирование -> программирование -> %много рефакторинга% -> соединение кусков вместе

Comment: @stck, это же диплом, правльно - последняя ночь - гугл - принтер - прошил - защитил.

Comment: хм... обычно в качестве дипломной работы выбирают ту тему, в которой разбираются. Или те времена уже прошли? Теперь только хардкор?

Comment: @Gorets, не сложилось у меня с этим :(

Comment: Время есть, поэтому хочется хардкора.

Comment: @Tyler, тогда почему C#, а не липс?

Comment: Потому что с C# я более-менее знаком.

Comment: @Tyler, хардкор же зато

Comment: на защите отдельную оценку за хардкорность не ставят. проверено =/

Comment: @stck, у всего есть границы. Даже у хардкора. Я пришел помощи просить, а вы скалитесь.

Comment: @Tyler, да не скалимся мы, но решили немного потроллить... Просто многих удивило/поразило/вызвало недоумение (нужное подчеркнуть) то, что вы в качестве темы для дипломной работы выбрали ту, в которой не разбираетесь. Мало того, что у вас будут проблемы во время работы над ней, так ее же еще и защитить нужно будет. Поэтому люди предположили, что вы не осилите это и в итоге скачаете готовый дефолтовый вариант... Так что все зависит от количестве свободного времени и от желания (_огромного желания_) изучать новые для вас технологии и экспериментировать.

PS. не сразу заметил ответ от @stck

Comment: Вот уже июль, а я смог) еще в июне на 5 защитил дипломку, все получилось!

Comment: Поздравляем.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Начните со структуры данных: какая БД, какова структура исходных данных, требуется ли нормализация.
2. Далее лепим образы данных - то что называется бины. В самом простом варианте: объект это запись в БД, поля базы данных переводятся в приватные члены класса.
3. Далее на основании полученных объектов в C# рисуем бизнес логику
4. На последнем этапе пишем веб морду - отображение безобразий выданных бизнес-логикой на веб. Это уже пишем под [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET)

Ну в общем что-то [типа такого](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture)

Comment: А можно 4 этап реализовать на ADO.NET?

Comment: п.5. в ночь перед защитой переходим к моему пункту.

Comment: @Gorets, не. п.5. - отчаяние. п.6. - ваш пункт

Comment: @Tyler я не силен в .NET, но насколько я понимаю ADO.NET это п. 2 - к веб морде это отношения не имеет